# Update tables in PostgreSQL database from MATLAB workspace

Tags: postgresql, matlab

I'd like to find out if i can update my PostgreSQL database from changes that i have done with the SQL tables that i have imported into the MATLAB workspace.

Are there functions from the Database Toolbox which does this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [Data Export](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/database/ug/f4-6010.html#f4-15451) section in Database Toolbox documentation.

The [UPDATE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/database/ug/update.html) function is probably what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into it. I was 50% sure about the method. Therefore i wanted to confirm the method. Thank you again.